# Await but return unexpected result ~ Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I create a search bar to search for data from an external API, so I make an `async` function to fetch data from the API. Here was where I encountered the problem.
In the function which is placed in the slice file, after fetching the data I can `console.log` the data, and it prints exactly what I need.
But in the component file in which I want to use that data to do stuff, when I take the data out by using `useSelector()` and then print it to the console, it returns an empty array `[]`.
Here is what my code in the component file looks like:

```
const result = useSelector(selectResult);

//This is the function that I pass in a value and it will dispatch an action
//And return a new value to the store
const search = async value => {
  await dispatch(fetchResult(value));
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are specifically asking about the `console.log(result);` in the `search` callback, why it remains an empty array `[]`, then you may want to research [Javascript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed)
> with references to its surrounding state (the **lexical environment**). In
> other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function's scope
> from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time
> a function is created, at function creation time.

In this case `search` function has a closure over the `result` variable which will have whatever the value is from the render cycle when `search` is called.  Regardless of what `await dispatch(fetchResult(value));` does to the store, the `result` value won't change in the callback handler.

Generally speaking, if you want to log out values *after they've updated* then you should use the `useEffect` hook with proper dependencies.

Example:

```
const result = useSelector(selectResult);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(result);
}, [result]);

const search = value => {
  dispatch(fetchResult(value));
};
```